# Regular expression: Remove first match pattern in front and behind certain text

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have the following text.

```
<span style="color:#FF0000;">赤色</span><span style="color:#0;">|*|</span><span style="color:#0070C0;">青色</span><span style="color:#0;">|*|</span><span style="color:#00B050;">緑色</span><span style="color:#0;">|*|</span>
```

I need to remove any span tag that defines color for "|*|" only. That is in this case, I need to remove

```
<span style="color:#0;">
```

and

```
</span>
```

Can anyone help to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What language are you using?

Comment: I am using .net. I tried match them in 3 capturing group and make the middle one Non-capturing. But seems it will all the string.(<span style=".*?>)(?:\|\*\|)(<\/span>)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
<span[^>]+style="[^"]*color:[^>]+>(\|\*\|)<\/span>
```

This matches `<span`, then one or more non-`>` characters, then a `style` attribute that contains `color:`, then the rest of the tag, then `|*|`, then `</span>`.

You would replace with `$1` or just `|*|`.

[Here's a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kE1NNx/1)

Note: one reason your attempt didn't work is that you escaped the `|`s, but not the `*`. You need to escape the `*` as `\*`.